# how to avoid more texture and textureRegion in andengine

Tags: andengine, game-engine

I am developing a game using andengine. For every sprite I need to create texture and `textureRegion`.

```
Texture bgTexture;

TextureRegion bgTextureRegion;

this.bgTexture = new Texture(512, 1024,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

  this.bgTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
            this.bgTexture, this, "gfx/bg.png", 0, 0);

Sprite bgSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.bgTextureRegion);
```

If I use `scoreSprite`, `lifeSprite`, etc I need to create a texture and `textureRegion` again & again for each sprite.

It increases the loading time of the game. Any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: hi.. i got solutio for loading dynamically texture and textureRegion   http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/dynamically-load-all-textures-texture-regions-t4139.html

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you need atlas & texture region for every sprite-type, not for every single sprite instance.

to avoid too many atlas instances and loading time from disk, you could use tiled png's for your graphics (many images on one larger png , up to 1024x1024 per png). then you can get your texture-region for a sprite-type with

```
TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(atlas, tiledX, tiledY, TILED_WIDTH, TILED_HEIGHT);
```

other hints and tricks are mentioned here:

http://www.matim-dev.com/tips-and-tricks---how-to-improve-performance.html

esp. the pooling, Spritebatch and Spritegroups, the culling and no theme background